# Timeline items in Adobe After Effects disappeared

Tags: adobe, after-effects, video-editing

Somehow my timeline in After Effect changed properties and now I can`t see (and move )the timeline items anymore. See at the right side of the screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d049V.png)

How can I get the timeline items back?

Comment: Hi CornKrue,
Have you tried to Reset the layout to "default Adobe Workspace"
Window>Workspace> Reset Standard

Otherwise you could remove the workspace from following folder:
fit for your needs:
(Windows) [drive]:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\After Effects\13.0\ModifiedWorkspaces

Comment: You are in graph mode, just click on the graph icon button which is blue on the left top of the layer list.